# Missing Fields Description in NetBeans generated javadocs

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc, documentation-generation

I'm using NetBeans 7.0.1 and I'm trying to generate the javadocs for one of my projects.

I tried both by right clicking the project -> Generate Javadoc and by Run -> Generate Javadoc. I managed to create the following javadocs sections:

- Constructor Summary
- Method Summary
- Constructor Detail
- Method Detail

but not the:

- Field Summary
- Filed Detail

How can I instruct the IDE with annotations, comments, or just through configuration to add that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "field summary" is created by javadoc using the first sentences of fields.

Field documentation should be generated automatically for public fields. To generate documentation for private and protected fields there's a checkbox option to include them in the project's Build/Documenting properties.